# Coupling from the past for continuous state space

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, stochastic-processes, convergence

[Coupling from the past](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_from_the_past) (CFTP) is a Markov chain Monte Carlo method for sampling exactly from a distribution. Briefly, in its vanilla form, CFTP **simultaneously simulates a Markov chain starting from each state in the state space**. Whenever two (or more) chains arrive at the same state during simulation, they coalesce (i.e., merge into a single Markov chain). Once all chains have coalesced into one final chain, the algorithm is terminated and that final state is a perfect sample from the stationary distribution.

This simulation is infeasible when the state space is infinite in size because we cannot simulate infinitely many chains. Does there exist a CFTP method for continuous state spaces? How does the method work and what's the intuition behind it?

Comment: The method works when one can find a finite number of "extreme" or "sandwiching" paths such that, when all these paths have coalesced into a single one, the non-denumerable others will have as well. Take for instance $[0,1]$ as the state space and the Markov chains starting from $0$ and $1$ as the extreme ones. The coupling mechanism should be designed in such a way that all other chains starting from $x\in[0,1]$ have already coalesced when these two Markov chains have coalesce.